# What open data institutes in the US are working with the Open Government Partnership?

Tags: usa, government

The [Open Government Partnership](http://www.opengovpartnership.org/about) (OGP) is a global alliance of countries that are signatory to an Open Government Declaration. The United States is one of the eight founding signatories - I am curious to know which organizations in the US are working on projects sponsored or supported by the OGP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have already seen this, but on the OGP website there is a Country Commitments page for each country including the [United States](http://www.opengovpartnership.org/countries/united-states). The "Efforts to Date" tab has some broad information on the government's, well, efforts to date. It appears that the main objective so far has been to increase the utility of the datasets available at [data.gov](http://www.data.gov/).

Data.gov looks to be a well-designed site with loads of information. For example you can dig down to Open Data sites at the [state and county level](http://www.data.gov/opendatasites). I suspect if you browse around you might find something approaching the information you're after.

As an aside, it seems that the OGP does not directly sponsor or financially support the work of individual groups or companies, etc. Rather they are an organisational body with the goal of spurring on governments to increase transparency. If you're interested in how the OGP's budget is sliced and diced, it is [available for download](http://www.opengovpartnership.org/ogp-budget).